# Why the name 'continue'

Tags: java, naming, keywords

The 'continue' keyword in Java (and probably in many other programming languages) is used to skip further execution of the current iteration.

Why was the name 'continue' chosen? Why not something more straightforward like 'skip' ?

Comment: Apart from the legacy of `C`? Why do you think "skip" is more straight forward than "continue"? Why not "jump over"? Why not "do again"?

Comment: @Oded Yup, it could be anything. 'skip' was just an example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While most likely not a very big difference and programmers would have been able to handle it just the same:

"continue" makes it clear that the loop will go on processing data (stop the details, continue the loop), while "skip" could be thought of as terminating the loop totally (like break in C++). It's one of those cases where it can be difficult to find the "perfect" name for some functionality. Ruby and Perl use "next" in similar situations which to me seems a slightly better choice.

Comment: The problem with `next` is that in some languages (e.g. Basic) `next` *is* the end of a `for` loop, so it might be confusing for some programmers with a background in those languages.

Comment: stopCurrentActionAndContinueProcessingFromTheNextItemInThisLoop;

Comment: @user281377: Do any languages other than BASIC use `next` to mark the end of a `for` loop?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen perfect! And thanks to modern IDEs long names are a problem of the past ;-)

Comment: @KeithThompson Probably most or all of them are basic dialects or derivates, but (almost) surprisingly, I find a lot of web sites that use the term "for-next-loop" to describe counting loops in other languages.

Comment: @user281377: I might suggest that web sites written by programmers whose first language was BASIC are not to be trusted -- if it weren't my own first language. 8-)}

Comment: @Keith: We are all spoiled :)

Comment: I think `continue` gives the wrong impression on what it does, or at least it would if I wasn't used to what it means. Saying "if X, then continue" followed by more instructions, normally implies that you should stop if not X. That's not how it works in programming of course, but I could still see it confusing newbies, or possibly even trip up an intermediate coder trying to work through an algorithm in his/her head. I think `skip` or `next` (maybe even `goto next`) would be a much more intuitive choice. (Though using `#define skip continue` or `next: }` would likely be even more confusing.)

Answer (score 12):

I guess it might have to do with history of programming languages.

To ask why it is continue in Java is to ask why it is continue in C++, which is to ask why it is continue in C, Algol etc.

To my knowledge, Fortran was the first to have a CONTINUE statement, actually a no op. It was just there to make it possible to place a (numeric) label used in goto or other constructs like:

```
    DO 42 i=1,100
    A[i] = 0
42  CONTINUE
```

The first line introduces a do loop that, when completed, continued execution at label 42.

Comment: It's ironic that other languages would borrow the statement from a language where it was a no-op.  I wonder how the loops were implemented on the old machines?  One DSP I used had an assembly-language instruction that worked like FORTRAN do-loop: one specified the address preceding the instruction following the loop, and it would set a special flag and load a special register with that address following that, and load another special register with the one following the "loop-start" instruction..  Whenever the code-fetch unit read a word from the first special register...

Comment: ...and the loop flag it was set, it would load the program counter with the value in the second, decrement a counter, and if it reached zero, clear the loop flag.  Like FORTRAN, the DSP forbade branching instructions immediately before the end of the loop (to avoid a pipeline stall, the program counter would get loaded with the loop start address before the last couple instructions were executed, so jumps there would cause confusion).

Comment: Not exactly so. In FORTRAN, the label in `DO` statement is the reference to the last statement of the loop (I believe that guys who designed INTERCAL, a parody programming language, drew their inspiration for COMEFROM statement from this feature of FORTRAN). In a loop like this you might put the label on assignment statement, but having a separate `CONTINUE` is handy if eventually you want to insert something at the end of loop body (especially if your program is on a batch of punched cards).

Answer (score 0):

I always thought of it as just continuing processing data and therefore it was named "continue". I have never seen anyone have issues with the choice of the continue keyword not being straightforward enough.

Comment: When you ask someone to continue they usually keep doing what they were doing but here the iteration is skipped. I think 'next' would have been a better suitable keyword as mentioned in the answer.